# Wildfly, JAAS and SecurityContext

Tags: jakarta-ee, wildfly, resteasy, jaas, security-context

I'm still playin with Wildfly-9.0.1.Final and JAAS (see my previous question [Wildfly and JAAS login module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33203277/wildfly-and-jaas-login-module)) in a web application that use a `BASIC auth-method`. While my custom login module works I got some problems about authorization. I use a RESTeasy RESTFul web service with annotation to test, here is the code:

```
package it.bytebear.web.mongo;

import it.bytebear.web.mongo.jaas.MongoModuleCallbackHandler;
import it.bytebear.web.mongo.model.User;

import java.security.Principal;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.security.PermitAll;
import javax.annotation.security.RolesAllowed;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.security.auth.Subject;
import javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Request;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response.Status;
import javax.ws.rs.core.SecurityContext;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

Path("/service")
Stateless
ublic class UserServices {

    private Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserServices.class);

    @GET
    @Path("/userA")
    @RolesAllowed({ "userA" })
    public Response postUserA() {
        return Response.ok("You're user A.", MediaType.TEXT_HTML).build();
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/userB")
    @RolesAllowed({ "userB" })
    public Response postUserB() {
        return Response.ok("You're user B.", MediaType.TEXT_HTML).build();
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/userC")
    @RolesAllowed({ "userC" })
    public Response postUserC() {
        return Response.ok("You're user C.", MediaType.TEXT_HTML).build();
    }

    @POST
    @Path("/login")
    @PermitAll
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    // @Consumes("application/x-authc-username-password+json")
    public Response login(User userCredentials) {
        log.info("logging in.");
        try {
            MongoModuleCallbackHandler handler = new MongoModuleCallbackHandler();
            handler.setUsername(userCredentials.getUserName());
            handler.setPassword(userCredentials.getPassword().toCharArray());
            LoginContext loginContext = new LoginContext("MongoLoginRealm", handler);
            loginContext.login();
            Subject subject = loginContext.getSubject();
            List<String> roles = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (Principal p : subject.getPrincipals()) {
                roles.add(p.getName());
            }
            String[] userCredentialsRoles = new String[roles.size()];
            roles.toArray(userCredentialsRoles);
            userCredentials.setRoles(userCredentialsRoles);
            return Response.ok().entity(userCredentials)
                    .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).build();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("login fails.", e);
            return Response.status(Status.FORBIDDEN).entity("Not logged")
                    .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).build();
        }
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/logout")
    @PermitAll
    public Response logout(Request req) {
        return Response.ok().build();
    }

    @POST
    @Path("/test")
    @PermitAll
    public Response test(@Context SecurityContext ctx) {
        Principal p = ctx.getUserPrincipal();
        return Response.status(Status.OK).entity(p).build();
    }
}
```

My login module is correctly invoked and generate a subjec with a `Group` named `Roles` containing a `Principal` named `userA`, but when I try to access `.../service/userA` I always get a `403` error. I use `test` method to check `subject` but `ctx.getUserPrincipal()` always return `null`. I miss how `LoginModule` and `SecurityContext` works, how `SecurityContext` knows about a Subject? More important: I'd like to learn more, link to resources and docs will be appreciated.

UPDATE:
In my `web.xml` I'm using RESTEasy security:

```
...
<context-param>
<param-name>resteasy.role.based.security</param-name>
<param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
...
```

Am I messing up EJB security with RESTEasy security?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue. I have the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

### Don't implement, configure

I suggest to avoid doing all the JAAS handling programmatically. Just use the application server configuration and security subsystem will take care of all the associations for you.

### RestEasy role-based security

RestEasy implements Role-based security. It has to be enabled in application's context parameter `"resteasy.role.based.security"` in `web.xml`.

```xml
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.role.based.security</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

If you don't use this parameter, then only the security constraints (in web.xml) are available for you for authorization configuration.

### Example

You can take some inspiration from my [sample app on GitHub](https://github.com/kwart/secured-webapp-template/) used for basic security testing. There is also a [Java package with REST resources](https://github.com/kwart/secured-webapp-template/tree/master/src/main/java/org/jboss/test/rest).

### Still not convinced?

Take a look at following code in the security subsystem implementation of WildFly:

- [SimpleSecurityManager](https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly/blob/9.0.1.Final/security/subsystem/src/main/java/org/jboss/as/security/service/SimpleSecurityManager.java#L349-L417)
- JbossAuthenticationManager extends [JaasSecurityManagerBase](https://github.com/picketbox/picketbox/blob/4.9.3.Final/security-jboss-sx/jbosssx/src/main/java/org/jboss/security/plugins/auth/JaasSecurityManagerBase.java#L281-L394)

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply. I agree with you, better configure than implement, but my objective is to learn :) I want to implement a custom login module maybe to use MongoDB with it. I read about Picketlink (Wildfly is my favorite AS) but I prefer to start with JAAS to learn. I put resteasy.role.based.security true in my web.xml too. I'd like to continue this way, can you lend me a hand?

Comment: Have you tried my testing application? It could give you solid overview of how to use the JAAS authentication in WildFly.